# Geolocation always timing out in cordova app

Tags: cordova, google-maps, geolocation, timeout, sencha-touch

I am working on a Sencha Touch (2.3.1) application, packaged using Cordova 3.5.0-0.2.7. I am trying to read GPS coordinates using:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()
```

But the request is always timing out on Android Phones, while it is working fine in Chrome emulator. I have tried using watchPosition() also.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What value of timeout did you set?

Comment: Do you have the appropriate Android permissions set in your config.xml?

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />

Comment: @GaëlMarziou I used values upto 1 minute for device, while the reponse is coming in a sec while trying in emulator.
And Yes I tried giving these permissions, but no luck with that too.

Comment: The problem was that the permissions were getting overwritten while building the application. Solved it with the plugin which adds permissions while building.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you've not already, install [cordova-plugin-geolocation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation) into your project - i.e. `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation` - this will add the appropriate permissions to your Android manifest, as [Mike Dailor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1766251/mike-dailor) rightly points out that you need.

What options are you passing as the third parameter to `getCurrentPosition()`? The [geolocationOptions](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation#geolocationoptions) object has 3 properties: timeout, maxAge and enableHighAccuracy.

Assuming you want an accurate position (i.e. GPS tracking/sat-nav type of app), setting `enableHighAccuracy: true` causes your app to ask the OS retreive a position using the GPS hardware. In this case, you want to set a timeout value which allows enough time for the GPS hardware to obtain a fix for the first time, otherwise the timeout will occur before it has a chance to get a fix.

Also bear in mind the that the effect of turning off GPS on an Android device (e.g. changing setting Location Mode to "Battery Saving") varies depending on the Android version: either the OS is never able to retreive a high-accuracy position, so the TIMEOUT error occurs (PERMISSION_DENIED will not be received on Android) or a low accuracy position will be retrieved and passed instead using Wifi/cell triangulation.

I'd suggest using watchPosition() instead of getCurrentPosition() to retrieve the location; getCurrentPosition() makes a single request for the device position at that current point in time, so the position timeout may occur before the GPS hardware on the device has had a chance to get a position fix, whereas using watchPosition() you can setup a watcher which will call the success function each time the OS receives a location update from the GPS hardware. If you only want a single location, clear the watcher after receiving a position of sufficient accuracy. If GPS is turned off on the Android device when the watcher is added, it will continue to return a TIMEOUT error; my workaround for this is to clear and re-add the watcher after a number of consequetive errors.

So something along these lines:

```
var MAX_POSITION_ERRORS_BEFORE_RESET = 3,
MIN_ACCURACY_IN_METRES = 20,
positionWatchId = null, 
watchpositionErrorCount = 0,
options = {
    maximumAge: 60000, 
    timeout: 15000, 
    enableHighAccuracy: true
};

function addWatch(){
    positionWatchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onWatchPositionSuccess, onWatchPositionError, options);
}

function clearWatch(){
    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(positionWatchId);
}

function onWatchPositionSuccess(position) {
    watchpositionErrorCount = 0;

    // Reject if accuracy is not sufficient
    if(position.coords.accuracy > MIN_ACCURACY_IN_METRES){
      return;        
    }

    // If only single position is required, clear watcher
    clearWatch();

    // Do something with position
    var lat = position.coords.latitude,   
    lon = position.coords.longitude;
}


function onWatchPositionError(err) {
    watchpositionErrorCount++;
    if (err.code == 3 // TIMEOUT
        && watchpositionErrorCount >= MAX_POSITION_ERRORS_BEFORE_RESET) {        
        clearWatch();
        addWatch();
        watchpositionErrorCount = 0;
    }

}
addWatch();
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip Dave. The problem was that the permissions were getting overwritten while building the application. Solved it with the plugin which adds permissions while building.

Also, As I am using Cordova < 5.0, above plugin does not apply, instead org.apache.cordova.geolocation should be used.

Comment: Along with this plugin, manually add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" /> in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @DaveAlden: sir i have tried above code but got position error for tell me sir why?

Answer (score 2):

Was battling with this issues until i found this plugin => https://github.com/louisbl/cordova-plugin-locationservices.

The plugin exists mainly because the cordova geolocation plugin does not use Android code anymore : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5977. It relies on the geolocation capability of the WebView. Don't know why no one is talking about this.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
 $scope.getCordinates= function() {
```

```
       if (window.cordova) {
        var PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY = 102;
        var posOptions = { maximumAge: 1000, timeout: 20000,enableHighAccuracy: false, priority: PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY };
        cordova.plugins.locationServices.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

             if(Location.init(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude)){

               $scope.Data.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
               $scope.Data.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
               //Toast.show('Getting Location...', 'short', 'top');

               }else{
                $scope.Data.latitude = '';
                $scope.Data.longitude = '';
                Toast.show('Turn on Location access in settings for better sales tracking..', 'short', 'bottom');
              }
            console.log(position);

          }, function(error) {
            $scope.Data.latitude = '';
            $scope.Data.longitude = '';
            Toast.show('Error encountered with Geolocation Api', 'short', 'bottom');
            console.log(error);

          }, posOptions);
        }

     }
```

Comment: Yes it did. Give it a shot, it won't fail you.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem and find a solution by doing this:

1. Add the plugin whitelist: ionic plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist.git
2. Don't forget to do a npm install each time you change dependencies.

I guess this problem was realated with the permissions somehow and whitelist solves it.

Good luck !